# Exponential of ladder operators acting on vacuum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, second-quantization, coherent-states

How would I solve expressions of the following nature:

$$<0|e^{Vt(a+a^\dagger)}|0>$$ and $$<0|e^{\omega aa^\dagger t}|0>~?$$

My intuition is that I have to expand the exponent as a power series but I can't understand how to deal with the pre-factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $aa^{\dagger}|0>=a|1>=|0>$. With this, its easy to see that $<0|aa^{\dagger}|0> = 1$, and then $<0|(aa^{\dagger})^2|0>=1$ and so on. you can generalize this for any $N \geq 0$:
$$
<0|\left( \omega t a a^{\dagger} \right)^{N}|0> \ = \ (\omega t)^N <0|\left(a a^{\dagger} \right)^{N}|0> \ = \ (\omega t)^N
$$

This means that:
$$
<0|e^{\omega t a a^{\dagger}}|0> \ = \ \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{<0|\left( \omega t a a^{\dagger} \right)^{N}|0>}{N!} \ = \ \sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\omega t)^N}{N!} \ = \ e^{\omega t}
$$

The process is the same for $<0|e^{Vt(a+a^{\dagger})}|0>$: Find an expression valid for any $N \geq 0$ for $<0|\left(Vt(a+a^{\dagger})\right)^N|0>$ and plug it into the power series.

Comment: It should be easy for you to answer the first question as well.